# There is no current wx.App object - creating one now

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, spectral-python

I am trying to visualize my hypercube data using `spectral` package and I follow the commands in the [main page](https://www.spectralpython.net/graphics.html) of spectral by `ipython --pylab=wx` and then I loaded the data to view::

```
import spectral
from pylab import *
from spectral import *
spectral.settings.WX_GL_DEPTH_SIZE = 16
hsi_root = "mypath_to_hsi/"
hypercubes = os.listdir(hsi_root)
hsi_list = os.listdir(hsi_root)
idx = 3
filename = "cube_envi32"
data_path = os.path.join(hsi_root, hsi_list[idx], filename)
# Load hypercube data
data = SpyFile.load(envi.open(data_path + '.hdr', data_path + '.dat'))  # (512, 640, 92)
```

when I am trying to view the cube , I am getting the following message:

```
view_cube(data,bands=[29, 19, 9])
There is no current wx.App object - creating one now.
  warnings.warn('\nThere is no current wx.App object - creating one now.',
Out[17]: <spectral.graphics.graphics.WindowProxy at 0x7f9dd694ef10>
```

and the output is a blank window. How to solve this?

**UPDATED:**
I added the following codes to initiate `wx.APP()`. I followed the [post here](https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/instance-of-wx-app/36663/2):

https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/instance-of-wx-app/36663/2

```
app = wx.App()
print(app)
print(wx.GetApp())
print(wx.App.Get())
print(wx.App.GetInstance())
print(wx.AppConsole.GetInstance())
```

it opens a pycharm window by showing nothing and then it forces to close the window
[image]

Comment: You show too little code, specially creating the app and its main window. Perhaps you want to follow [this simple example](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20by%20Example)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, did you try to contact the author of that Python library you are trying to use?

Comment: @Igor you're addressing the wrong person. please figure out why you mistook me for the author of the question, and how to avoid that.

Comment: @S.EB, did you try to contact the author of that Python library you are trying to use?

Comment: @Igor Thanks for your comment. yes and this is my question in their [github page](https://github.com/spectralpython/spectral/issues/163#issue-2056974341)